# Classic thesis, centered table with left justified text

Tags: tables

I am making a centered table on Classic Thesis but need the headings in the far left column to be left-justified instead of fully justified.

Table code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{tabular}{m{2.5cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1cm} m{1cm}}
    \hline
    Condition & 3 yo & 4 yo & 5 yo & 6 yo & 7 yo & 8 yo & adults \\
    \hline
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{General results from Experiment 1}
    \label{resultadostask1table}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome in [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) :-)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a short, but complete compile-able example, rather than just a code snippet.

Comment: I think you could use `\multicolumn{1}{align}{Condition}` in order to fine tune the alignment of a single cell. In your case the top left one.

Comment: Do you have any reason to specify the column widths? It seems you might as well use `\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}`